# IBM Bluemix API key error with Python

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to use Python to program watson_developer_cloud and I am getting an API key error. My code is really simple:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 as VisualRecognition

visual_recognition = VisualRecognition('2016-05-20', api_key='<myAPIkey>')
test_url = 'https://www.ibm.com/ibm/ginni/images/ginni_bio_780x981_v4_03162016.jpg'

print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.classify(images_url=test_url)))
```

But for some reason when I run it, I get a SSL error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'gateway-a.watsonplatform.net' doesn't match either of 'access.alchemyapi.com', 'www.access.alchemyapi.com'

I know the API key (omitted above) works because when I use CURL or NodeJS it works just fine.

I am really stumped. Could someone please help?

Comment: Update: Interestingly I discovered that if I access the Watson using CURL, things work out just fine. So it seems to be related to have requests/SSL is being handled and it is definitely not an issue with IBM Watson servers.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It turns out you require python>=2.7.8 because of server name identification (SNI). My version of python is 2.7.3, and it does not support that and therefore I am getting the error seen above.

So this is why CURL and other attempts to use the API key work, whereas my python was generating a SSLError. Happy upgrading!

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Hack:**
Change the file - `watson_developer_cloud_service.py:243` as below:

```
diff watson_developer_cloud_service.py watson_developer_cloud/watson_developer_cloud_service.py
243c243
<                                     params=params, data=data, files=files, verify=False, **kwargs)
---
>                                     params=params, data=data, files=files, **kwargs)
```

after that -

```
rm -f /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud-0.14.0-py2.7.egg
```

followed by ..

```
python setup.py install
```